# How to convert from ES6 to ES5(arrow function)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sapui5, ecmascript-5

I am trying to convert ES6 arrow function to ES5

I have already trying to change it but it lose its scope because I 'm using this.getView()

```
this.getModel().read('/CharacteristicSet', {
  filters: this._afilters,
  success: function (oData) {
    oViewModel.setProperty('/charSet', oData.results);

    for (let i = 0; i < oData.results.length; i++) {
      if (oData.results[i].GroupId === sKey) {
        oBinding.filter(this._mFilters[sKey]);
      }
    }

    let aIconTabItems = this.byId('iconTabBar').getItems();
    let aCharacteristics = oData.results;

    for (var j = 0; j < aIconTabItems.length; j++) {
      let count = aCharacteristics.filter(
        obj =>
          obj.GroupId === aIconTabItems[j].getKey() &&
          obj.EquipmentNumber ===
            this.getView()
              .getBindingContext()
              .getProperty('EquipmentNumber'),
      ).length;

      oViewModel.setProperty(`/${aIconTabItems[j].getKey()}`, count);
    }
  }.bind(this),
});
```

I am expecting it to be ES5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the `thisArg` of [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

> **thisArg**: Optional - Value to use as `this` when executing callback.

Particularly, and speaking about the arrow function you are trying to convert, you can pass the `this` context from the `success` callback to be used inside the filter() as `this`:

```
var count = aCharacteristics.filter(function(obj)
{
    var equipmentNum = this.getView().getBindingContext().getProperty("EquipmentNumber");
    return obj.GroupId === aIconTabItems[j].getKey() && obj.EquipmentNumber === equipmentNum;
}, this /* Here we use the thisArg of filter */).length;
```

The other way, is just to define a variable outside the `loop`, like you are doing with variable `aIconTabItems`:

```
let aIconTabItems = this.byId('iconTabBar').getItems();
let aCharacteristics = oData.results;
let equipmentNum = this.getView().getBindingContext().getProperty('EquipmentNumber');

for (var j = 0; j < aIconTabItems.length; j++)
{
    let count = aCharacteristics.filter(function(obj)
    {
        return obj.GroupId === aIconTabItems[j].getKey() &&
               obj.EquipmentNumber === equipmentNum;
    }).length;

    oViewModel.setProperty(`/${aIconTabItems[j].getKey()}`, count);
}
```